# What are some significant places of un-touched natural beauty, traditional culture and history in Thailand?

Tags: thailand, nature-and-wildlife, culture, history

My sister, Brother in Law and Partner are heading to Thailand in July this year for 2 weeks. We are flying into Bangkok and flying out of Phuket.

What are some of the cultural, natural and historical highlights in Thailand? Are there some places 'off the beaten track'?

Comment: Sorry, we can't do recommendations here. These are too opinion-based.

Comment: I have edited my question, Is it acceptable now? If not is there a way I can frame it to gather information without breaking the rules? Thanks :)

Comment: Thailand is a pretty big country and this question is way too broad. I think where you want to start is Wikivoyage.